# SFML не может загрузить изображение из директории с программой

Tags: c++, opengl, visual-studio-2017, sfml

Использую простенькую функцию для загрузки и создания OpenGL текстуры:

```
GLuint loadTexture(sf::String name)
{
    sf::Image image;
    image.loadFromFile(name);

    image.flipVertically();

    GLuint texture = 0;
    glGenTextures(1, &texture);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture);
    gluBuild2DMipmaps(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_RGBA, image.getSize().x, image.getSize().y, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, image.getPixelsPtr());
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_NEAREST_MIPMAP_NEAREST);

    return texture;
}
```

Когда вызываю функцию таким образом:

`texture = loadTexture("Images/player.png");`

Выдаёт ошибку:

`Failed to load image "Images/player.png". Reason: Unable to open file`

Но если вызываю с полным путём к файлу:

`texture = loadTexture("C:/Users/Ivan/source/repos/Engine/x64/Release/Images/player.png");`

Тогда отлично находит и отрисовывает файл.
Подскажите в чём может быть дело.

Comment: Слеш у вас нетот скорее всего.

Comment: @nick_n_a а почему тогда во втором случае с этим же слэшем всё работает?

Comment: `Images/player.png` будет работать, если текущей директорией программы является `C:/Users/Ivan/source/repos/Engine/x64/Release` студийные проекты обычно используют в качестве текущей директорию проекта. Текущую директорию для запуска можно указать в настройках проекта, на вкладке `Debugging`.

Comment: @VTT Можно по подробней?

Comment: @VTT Как можно решить данный вопрос? Целесообразно ли получать директорию от куда была запущена программа и дальше относительно этой директории искать нужные файлы, и если целесообразно то как это ренализовать? Или стоит поискать другое решение данной проблемы?

Comment: Тут на самом деле много вариантов. Можно получить и путь к exe (`GetModuleFileNameW`), можно прочитать путь к директории программы из реестра. Можно установить текущую директорию вызвав `SetCurrentDirectory` и использовать относительные пути, а можно и самому составлять полный путь к файлу.

Comment: @VTT А можно пример с использованием GetModuleFileNameW

Comment: Если вы работаете под виндой, то посмотрите, что показывает функция GetCurrentDirectory(). При запуске программы от имени админа/в режиме отладки, емнип, этот путь может меняться. Если хотите работать с относительными путями, то можно двигать базовую директорию приложения через SetCurrentDirectory(). Дополнительно при отладке из студии в свойствах проекта, на вкладке Debugging есть поле Working Directory, которое определяет стартовый каталог приложения